# SQL statement before 3 days

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using this query to get dates from MYSQL DB to show before current date. I want to show records using the current system date and before 3 days

```
SELECT gsu.id, gsuo.user_id, gsob.imei, gsob.vin, gsob.dt_tracker
 FROM gs_users gsu
 INNER JOIN gs_user_objects gsuo
 ON gsu.id = gsuo.user_id
 INNER JOIN gs_objects gsob
 ON gsuo.imei = gsob.imei
 WHERE gsu.id = '14' AND gsob.dt_tracker < CURDATE() AND vin <> ''
```

I have also tried

```
DATEADD(day, -3, gsob.dt_tracker)
```

AND

```
DATEADD(day, -3, GETDATE())
```

The result then does not show.

Comment: dateadd and getdate are both sql-server functions are you sure you are using mysql? - please add the result of select version().

Comment: I see I am using 10.6.4-MariaDB

Comment: ```... WHERE ... date_column {operator} CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 3 DAY, ...```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For MySQL you need to use `DATE_ADD()` [function](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_add.asp) with interval parameter

```
date_add(curdate(), interval -3 day) -- today minus 3 days
```

Here's [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=267c5f4d45572ec73e052107682d9435) example how to use.

Comment: Of course the correct way. You could add that using DATE(datetoCompare) allows to ignore the time when comparing if this is intended.